# print data from database but getting only variable name

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my function. I need to print data from the table. how can I print?

I'm getting only category, question & answer as a word. but I want to print data from the database.

```
function tbq_structure($atts)
{
    global $wpdb;
    global $tableData;   
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "pte_question";
  $sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * from $table_name where id=4" );
  $category = 'category';
  $question = 'question';
  $answer = 'answer';
  $tableData.='<table style="width:100%">';
  $tableData.='<tr>';
  $tableData.='<th>'.$category.'</th>';
  $tableData.='<th>'.$question.'</th>';
  $tableData.='<th>'.$answer.'</th>';
  $tableData.='</tr>';
  $tableData.='</table>';
  return $tableData;

}
add_shortcode('tbq', 'tbq_structure');
```

Comment: You define `$category = 'category';` so it will echo "category". If you want the values from the databse, read up on [fetching data from a query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: I have put echo "category"; but still not showing value.

Comment: `echo "category";` is telling it to output the exact string `"category"`, so of course that's what it does. If you didn't know that, you maybe need to study the basics of PHP before you go any further.

Comment: Anyway I don't know Wordpress but https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/ says the method returns an object (when there's only one result from the database). Try `echo $user->category;` and see if that helps. (P.S. You can also run `var_dump($user);` to see what other properties are available for you to read from the result).

Comment: @Community P.S. I disagree with the nominated duplicate because a) it's not Wordpress-specific and b) the accepted answer is years out of date. Voting to re-open.